# oracle.sql.DATUM is deprecated. What is its replacement?

Tags: java, oracle, deprecated

I inherited some legacy Java at work and it's making use of `oracle.sql` import. I've managed to import `java.sql` instead and make minor alterations to the class references of the legacy code, and everything seems to be working fine; however, I've stumbled upon a `Datum` object. I'm trying to find its equivalent in `java.sql` but I have no idea what `Datum` does, or what it even means. There does not appear to be a class inside of `java.sql` with `Datum` objects, so I'm wondering what is its replacement.

I've checked out Oracle's documentation @ https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/Datum.html
and it's not very helpful, at least not to me.

**Here's a snippet just for the purpose of seeing how the class was being used in the legacy**

```
  import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
  import oracle.sql.Datum;       


  ARRAY arr = getArray(dataRow, "FORM_DATA", false);
  Map<String, String> kvMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  try {                 
        Datum[] dat = arr.getOracleArray();
         for (int i=0;i<dat.length;i++){
             Object[] element = ((oracle.sql.STRUCT) dat[i]).getAttributes();
             String key = (String)element[0];
             String value = (String)element[1];
             kvMap.put(key, value); 
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.logError(this, e.getMessage());
    }
    ....
```

The `getOracleArray()` method can be seen here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/ARRAY.html#getOracleArray_long__int_

Comment: It seems that this class was used as superclass for specific types. In java.sql you have direct definition of the specific types.

Comment: I admit I'm not familiar with oracle DB, but I suggest you to check all of *direct known subclasses* (in the link you provided)

Comment: Since the doc you linked to says it's `abstract`, you can't instantiate it; so it might be interesting to see how your legacy code is using it. Where does it say it's deprecated, incidentally?

Comment: I added a snippet of code. Perhaps it will provide additional context. I'll check out it's subclasses and see if I strike gold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the code shown retrieves an array of structs consisting of key and value each, i.e. a map.

Based on what I gleaned from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/oraoot2.htm) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html) I would expect the JDBC compliant code to look something like the following

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Struct;

// getArray() must be modified to return a java.sql.Array, but that should be
// nothing but rs.getArray() (or dataRow.getArray())
Array arr = getArray(dataRow, "FORM_DATA", false);
Map<String, String> kvMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
try {                 
   Struct[] dat = (Struct[])arr.getArray();
   for (Struct s : dat) {
       Object[] element = s.getAttributes();
       String key = (String)element[0];
       String value = (String)element[1];
       kvMap.put(key, value); 
   }
} catch (SQLException e) {
   Log.logError(this, e.getMessage());
}
```

Haven't tested it, but if you're not using any Oracle specific methods it should be relatively straight forward.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out after I read your links. Yesterday, I just changed `Datum` array to `Date` array, and my ide didn't complain so I just went with it, lol. I'll read the links and post my findings!